# Java: SQL and Statistics/Machine Learning

Tags: java, sql, statistics

I have a question for you concerning Java. I am basically a Java user and did most of my work with it. However, in the machine learning classes I took in college, we used mostly python with the scikit-learn and numpy packages.

Now I want to do a project where I crawl data from the web, store it in SQL databases, and then do machine learning on this data. Maybe some of you have experience with those things and share some of it? I mean, of course it is possible to do these things with java, but maybe you have had some particular experiences on why I should use something else or what to consider?

I am happy for all your thoughts :-)

Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that programming language and database implementation are secondary problems. Think first about the machine learning you want to do. Review the existing packages (in any language) and pick one according to how well it fits the needs of the business problem you are trying to solve. Then work with whatever language is most convenient for that package. You will probably find that no single language is suitable for all parts of the problem; you will end up gluing together Java, Python, R, shell scripts, etc, to make a complete solution, and there's nothing wrong with that. Consider that your job is problem solving instead of programming in a specific language and go from there.